# Autofill password and email javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autofill

I have a problem with autofill feauture of my browser. Once a user logins with her email and password, browser holds these two information for future reference. When she opens login page, email and password fields are populated by browser. Event which I binded using jquery for email   triggered. On the other hand event for password isn't triggered.

Login form contains following lines:

```
<form method="post" action="/login" id="login-form">
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email" id="email" name="email"/>
    <input type="password"  placeholder="Password" id="password"  name="password"/>
    <button type="submit" />
</form>
```

My script file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {    

$("#email").on('change keyup paste mouseup',function () {
    alert("email");
});    
$("#password").on('change keyup paste mouseup',function () {
    alert("password");
});

});

</script>
```

These two fields are populated by browser successfully. But only "email" messages is shown. Event which is for password isn't triggered.

Any suggestions ?

Thanks.

Comment: You didn't close your `.ready(` or either  `.on(` so you're missing three `)` parens. Granted, I'd expect that to throw from the beginning - because you said that "the email message is shown", this leads me to believe it was just a typo in your question.

Comment: Use console.log instead of alert

Comment: @Santi I did't missed them in my login page. Just forgot to post here. I edited the code

Comment: @Musa, I have used console.log. It prints email but not password

Comment: I think this is a bug as discussed in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35049555/chrome-autofill-autocomplete-no-value-for-password