# GWT SENCHA password field not validating correctly on browser fill

Tags: java, gwt, sencha-touch, gxt

I have the following code to check whether my password field isValid, which then enables the login button.

```
Scheduler.get().scheduleFixedDelay(new Scheduler.RepeatingCommand() {
            @Override
            public boolean execute() {
                login.setEnabled(isValid());  // checks password field
                return !hasLoggedIn;
            }
        }, 100);
```

However my

```
private PasswordField password;
```

returns null all the time even when filled/remembered by browser - until a key is pressed/mouse clicked. If I press any key, or click the mouse button (anywhere on webpage), the password field then returns a value (and validates correctly).

How can I auto enable login button when browser filled password field is remembered ?

Comment: If it happens in Chrome only, then may be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35049555/chrome-autofill-autocomplete-no-value-for-password

Comment: Why not using a KeyPressHandler?

Comment: @ElHoss to do what exactly ? It won't solve my problem.

Comment: I understood, that you would like to check the input of the password to enable a login button if the password is correct.

Comment: @ElHoss try reading it again.

Comment: Got it ... Are you using getValue()?

Comment: @ElHoss getcurrentvalue i think

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148330/discussion-between-el-hoss-and-nimchimpsky).

Answer (score 0):

```
String bgColor = cell.getAppearance().getInputElement(passwordField.getElement()).getComputedStyle("background-color");
```

And then if its yellow I can enable button.

Hacktastic!