# Chrome autofill filling in email and password but not showing value, even after submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, google-chrome

I have a sign up form where the user enters their name, email, and password. When the user clicks into the email input field to enter their email, Chrome provides a suggested email and password for the two different input fields. I'm using jQuery to get the value of the input fields and send them to an external api. Sometimes, when a user clicks on the suggested input for email, it will only show the value for the email but not for the password, even though Chrome shows the user that there is a value in the field. I realize that this is an issue with Chrome caused by its security features. Supposedly, the values are supposed to appear on submit, but I can't seem to make it work. Since I'm submitting to an external api and have to gather other data from things like cookies, I've tried submitting a request to a hidden iframe and then sending the api request but the values still appear as empty. I've also tried tricking Chrome to not autofill in the fields, but this does not work as I want since I'm having the same issue with the email field when a user fills in a password using autofill. Does anyone know how to make the values appear when they are autofilled in?

Comment: Late on this response, but the answer you need is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35049555/chrome-autofill-autocomplete-no-value-for-password