# Text input's "value" attribute is incorrect

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js, autofill

I have a single input in my Vue app. It's a part of a component, which is set up like the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components) on the usage of “v-model with components”:

```
Vue.component('custom-input', {
  props: ['value'],
  template: `
    <input
      v-bind:value="value"
      v-on:input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)"
    >
  `
})
```

This input is clearly is filled with a value (from Chrome autofill) when the page loads, but in my code I have the following statement:

```
setInterval(() => { console.log(document.querySelector('input').value); }, 50);
```

This *consistently* logs an empty string even while I can plainly see that that input is filled with a value. However, as soon as I inspect or reference the element in Chrome devtools, the `setInterval` suddenly begins logging the correct value (`luke@deentaylor.com`):

[image]
Since the problem disappears as soon as one attempts to debug it, this has been extremely difficult to diagnose. What could cause this?

**EDIT:** never mind, this behavior has nothing to do with the inspection of the element itself, a `console.log('hi')` in the console produces the same result. The prerequisite for filling the correct form value is just for the user to interact with the page. Unlike the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35049555/chrome-autofill-autocomplete-no-value-for-password), I do need the full autofilled value; my login form needs to make a request to the server with the contents of the field before enabling the "submit" button.

Comment: where are your putting `setIntervale...`?

Comment: [This article](https://medium.com/@brunn/detecting-autofilled-fields-in-javascript-aed598d25da7) may be useful.

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim It's irrelevant where the setInterval is, it's referencing global variables to find the input and the `setInterval` is working correctly. It's being called in the `mounted` hook of one of my components, though.

Comment: @RoyJ thanks. Having a method to detect autofill on the inputs is useful, but still doesn't let me see the field's value.

Comment: Possibly generating a `click` event in the page will make fields aware of their autofilled values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is just expected behavior for Chrome's autofill. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35049555/chrome-autofill-autocomplete-no-value-for-password) question.

Comment: That's disappointing; my app needs to make a server request with the contents of the input before enabling a "submit" button, and if there's no way to get the contents of autofilled credentials before the user interacts, I may need to simply disable autofill :/

Comment: I'll wait a little while to accept your answer just in case anybody else comes up with a solution

Comment: I don't blame you, I hope someone does.

Comment: The supposition in the linked question's answer is correct. It is a security measure to block malicious pages from using hidden inputs to steal auto-filled information