# How can i get the autofilled input value?

Tags: javascript, autofill

On a login page, I have managed to catch the autofill to adapt the input display. Now I would need to validate the data itself, but I can't get the input value, it is empty.

```html
<label title="signInEmailAddress" for="signInEmailAddress">
    <span class="">Email</span>
    <input id="signInEmailAddress" type="text" name="signInEmailAddress" required="true" />
</label>
```

```
let autoFillInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input:-webkit-autofill');
setTimeout(() => {
    if (autoFillInputs) {
        autoFillInputs.forEach(function(autoFillInput) {
            let label = autoFillInput.closest('label');
            if (label) {
                label.classList.add('active');
            }
            setTimeout(() => {
                let value = autoFillInput.value;
                if (value) {
                    Form.validateInput(autoFillInput);
                }
            }, 50);
        });
    }
}, 500);
```

How can i get the value? These are text inputs (username and password)

Comment: please add HTML snippet

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35049555/chrome-autofill-autocomplete-no-value-for-password