# Vuetify Text field show value and label in first load because autofill

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

When first load the value from autofill and label both show above each other and when I click anywhere on-page the field become normal
Any Help I try A lot of thing like **:placeholder="' '"**
[image]

```
<v-text-field
            v-model="email"
            :rules="emailRules"
            :label="$t('auth.email')"
            required
            solo
            outlined
            flat
            dense
            color="primary"
            :placeholder="' '"
            prepend-icon="mdi-email"
            @keypress.enter="login"
            autocomplete="email"
          ></v-text-field>
```

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: @ManiMirjavadi I edit my question

Comment: I think this happens because your browser is showing the saved email and password for the inputs and Vue cannot understand that the inputs are filled. Check it without the saved inputs and see if the problem still exists.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63264017/how-fix-issue-with-chrome-auto-complete-overlap-with-labels-in-vuetify

Answer (score 1):

I Solve it by adding autocomplete="new" for my input with type="text"
and autocomplete="new-password" for my input with type=""password

```
<v-text-field
            :type="passwordType ? 'text' : 'password'"
            :append-icon="passwordType ? 'mdi-eye' : 'mdi-eye-off'"
            @click:append="passwordType = !passwordType"
            v-model="password"
            :rules="[passwordRules.required]"
            :label="$t('auth.password')"
            required
            solo
            outlined
            flat
            dense
            color="primary"
            :placeholder="' '"
            prepend-icon="mdi-lock"
            @keypress.enter="login"
            autocomplete="new-password"
          ></v-text-field>

<v-text-field
            v-model="email"
            :rules="emailRules"
            :label="$t('auth.email')"
            required
            solo
            outlined
            flat
            dense
            color="primary"
            :placeholder="' '"
            prepend-icon="mdi-email"
            @keypress.enter="login"
            autocomplete="new"
          ></v-text-field>
```

Hope that help every one