# How to avoid overlapping of Angular mat-label with browser autofill?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

Here is password field code (Angular 15, Chrome 114.0.5735.199 (Official Build) (64-bit))

```
            <mat-form-field>
              <mat-label translate>common.password</mat-label>
              <input id="password-input" matInput type="password" formControlName="password" required/>
              <toggle-password matSuffix></toggle-password>
              <mat-icon matPrefix>lock</mat-icon>
            </mat-form-field>
```

And here is how it looks right after loading login page. The browser autofill and mat-label overlap.
[image]

Comment: What browser? Would disable auto fill make sense for u?

Comment: Chrome 114.0.5735.199 (Official Build) (64-bit) I wish to enable autofill

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it for angular material 17 by using css:

```
mat-form-field:has(input:-webkit-autofill) .mdc-floating-label {
  --mat-mdc-form-field-label-transform: translateY(-30.75px)
    scale(var(--mat-mdc-form-field-floating-label-scale, 0.75));
  transform: var(--mat-mdc-form-field-label-transform);
  font-size: var(--mat-form-field-outlined-label-text-populated-size);
}
```

The solution is not perfect but simple.

[You can find an example for plain html labels here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63908091/angular-6-chrome-autofill-label-overlapping-issue)