# Chrome autofill overlapping floating label

Tags: css

I implemented [this](https://codepen.io/abergin/pen/vYmaPE) form design which moves the label out of the input field with [`:valid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:valid).
The issue is that on page load, my browser fills in my saved credentials and the CSS rules under `:valid` are not taken into account.
When I click on a blank space or anywhere really on the page, it works.
I want it to work without the user having to make an action, JS would be an option if necessary. I already tried to fire up a `click` event, but it does not do anything, I have to click manually to execute the CSS below `:valid`.

[image: GIF to illustrate issue]

```css
.form-input-group input:valid~label {
  transform: translate(0, -200%);
}

.form-input-group input:valid {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.form-input-group input:focus~label {
  transform: translate(0, -200%);
}

.form-input-group input:focus {
  outline: none;
  background: #ff4a56;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.form-input-group label,
.form-input-group input {
  transition: all 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.53, 0.01, 0.35, 1.5);
}

.form-input-group {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.form-input-group:first-of-type {
  padding-top: 0;
}

.form-input-group:last-of-type {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.form-input-group label {
  transform-origin: left center;
  color: #ff4a56;
  font-weight: 100;
  letter-spacing: 0.01em;
  font-size: 17px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(0, -100%);
  z-index: 2;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.form-input-group input {
  appearance: none;
  background-color: none;
  border: 1px solid #ff4a56;
  line-height: 0;
  font-size: 17px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-radius: 60px;
  color: #ff4a56;
  font-weight: 100;
  letter-spacing: 0.01em;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="get">
  <div class="form-input-group">
    <input type="text" required/>
    <label>First Name</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-input-group">
    <input type="text" required/>
    <label>Last Name</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-input-group">
    <input type="text" required/>
    <label>Email Address</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-input-group">
    <input type="password" required/>
    <label>Email Confirm</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

#### Edit

Fun fact: even a huge site like reddit is victim to this chromium big brain decision.

[image: reddit login]

Comment: You could try calling `checkValidity()` on the `form` after a timeout on page load. Note that [autocomplete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete] with form fields is ... controversial, with Chrome in particular taking a different stance from other browsers.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Hey good suggestion. I've tried it and `checkValidity` is false after page load and timeout, but after I click somewhere in the DOM, `checkValidity` is true https://imgur.com/a/jFsjXKS  W T F chrome. Like the value doesn't exist until I click somewhere, really well done I have to say.

Comment: Yep, the value is really NOT in the input field before the user clicks somewhere. `console.log(emailInput.value)` is `false` on page load and timeout but `true` after I click on the header I'm left almost speechless. Are they trying to make our life hard or why doesn't it populate the input value like my password manager Bitwarden does. Beautifully inserting the values and works so well with animation and all. Chrome puts a kind of overlay of bulky text in the wrong size and font with a background color on the input field. How are we supposed to make it look pretty if they don't follow rules?

Comment: Typo above: `emailInput.value` is not `false` obviously, but an empty string and after the user clicks somewhere it contains the email address. Here is a gif showing it https://imgur.com/a/UBieuny
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=748968 and a lot of other issues related to chrome breaking the floating label and more UI styling. Closed WontFix, nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that this is unfixable because of the stubbornness of chromium decision makers, despite the seemingly general [confusion and frustration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35049555/chrome-autofill-autocomplete-no-value-for-password) of web devs since 2014 and other browsers behaving differently.

[This](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=748968) is one of the many chromium bug tickets that were closed as WontFix.

[Here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=762361) are [some](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=669724) [others](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=636425).

#### Edit

Via [this](https://rojas.io/how-to-detect-chrome-autofill-with-vue-js/) article, I saw [`:-webkit-autofil`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/:autofill) and did some testing, and it seems to kind of work like I wanted. Let's just hope that it'll be working consistently over time.

[image: working floating label]