HTMX inline validation & browser autofill
Consider the following input:
<input class="form-control"
       id="phone"
       type="tel"
       hx-post="/validate"
       hx-select="#phone-number-validation"
       hx-target="#phone-number-validation"/>

When a user autofills on a different input, consequently filling the telephone number input, there is no request sent.
How to ensure inline validation requests are sent when inputs are autofilled?

What browser are you using? If Chrome, have you tried Firefox? I think this might be related to this question where you can't read autofill values until the user interacts with it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35049555/chrome-autofill-autocomplete-no-value-for-password
